# PyPlot.pltm is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, ubuntu-14.04, julia

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 platform. I have installed Julia, Anaconda etc.

When I try to plot on IJulia using PyPlot, I get the following error.

```
julia> Pkg.add("PyPlot")
INFO: Nothing to be done

julia> using PyPlot

julia> x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000); y = sin(3*x + 4*cos(2*x));

julia> PyPlot.plot(x, y, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--")
ERROR: pltm not defined
 in plot at /home/cgmei/.julia/v0.3/PyPlot/src/PyPlot.jl:368
```

Is pltm part of some other package.

Comment: Have you installed `python` and `matplotlib`?

Comment: Yes, I have. Both packages are installed

Answer (score -2):

When you want to call external python packages in julia you will need to call them in a different way than you did. In your example what you should do is:

```
    Pkg.add("PyCall")
    using PyCall
    @pyimport pylab
    x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000); y = sin(3*x + 4*cos(2*x));
    pylab.plot(x,y, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--")
    pylab.show()
```

If I want to use another python library as an example to clarify, assuming I have already added the package PyCall:

```
    using PyCall
    @pyimport numpy
    x = numpy.linspace(0,2*pi,1000)
```

And the result of this code will show part (since it won't show all 1000 elements) of the numpy array being used.

Comment: _"you will need to call them in a different way "_  Actually OP's code runs fine without modification on JuliaBox and locally.  Something must not be right with his install and/or dependencies.